Why changing height affects the effect of boxShadow

This is what it looks like, changing the height of the element results in the shadow effect also changing, out of the blue, please enlighten me, thank you.


function inputHandle(e) {
  document.getElementById('shadow').style.height = `${e.target.value}px`;
}
#shadow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  margin: 60px;
}
<label for="num">height</label>
<input type="number" value="1" id="num" oninput="inputHandle(event)">
<div id="shadow"></div>




Changing the height of the box, also changes the shadow of the box - not sure how this surprises you?

nothing is explicitly written about this in doc/spec but it is indeed written that shadows are CASTED. With all of these parameters we have it feels weird that shadows are still kinda unpredictable

Given the blur is fixed at 10px I cannot see why the height of the element should in any way affect it - it isn't a 'real' shadow (in the sense of a taller person casting a longer shadow), the blur radius has been fixed. Hope someone can explain further!

The intensity of the box shadow is due to the blur spread as the height gets larger..
You can get around this by adjusting your blur when the height changes.
You will see how adjusting the blur radius reduces the intensity.


    function inputHandle(e) {
        const height = e.target.value;
        const blurRadius = height * 10; // Adjust the factor as needed
        document.getElementById('shadow').style.height = `${height}px`;
        document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = `0 0 ${blurRadius}px red`;
    }
    #shadow {
        width: 100px;
        height: 1px;
        background: #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
        margin: 60px;
        transition: height 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s; /* Smooth transition for better observation */
    }
<label for="num">height</label>
<input type="number" value="1" id="num" oninput="inputHandle(event)">

<div id="shadow"></div>




Why does the height of the element affect the blur in any way? I can't find this in the spec - and for larger heights (around 5px+) the look of the shadow seems pretty consistent.
